# How should I render a 2D flashlight effect?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a flashlight effect in my 2D game. My flashlight is represented as a line segment extending from the entity at a specific angle. The flashlight can point in any direction. The flashlight also varies in intensity (length of the flashlight beam).

I'm have a problem trying to figure out the best (easiest?) and most flexible way to render the flashlight effect. Particularly with the tiled map.

I can think of two methods. But I have no idea to implement them:

1. ONLY draw a conical/circle-segment part of the tiled map
2. covering the screen with a black texture, and with code punching a hole into the black texture. This way I can change attributes of the hole.

I'm clueless as to where to start with this/what these are called/if libGDX can do them.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://piledriverengine.com/images/flashlightBeam.png

Comment: Yes, but I want to lengthen/shorten the beam as the flash light's "battery" dies. The obvious way would be to scale the image, but at some point that'll show the map. Plus isn't it bad practice to make a GIANT black texture?

Answer (score 6):

**Number one** is called stencil buffer. But you'll find it difficult to achieve soft effects. -- Easy.

**Number two:** You just need a texture with the light. The completely black areas can be drawn repeating a black sprite around the light sprite (left, right, up, down). Or you can mix it with the stencil buffer. Or you can carefully calculate your texture coordinates and use GL.clamp_to_edge to propagate all the black pixels. Depending on how you render your scene, you can  render your light first with alpha information and then blend the scene (darkening according to the dst_alpha). -- Not that hard to implement.

**Number three** would be research on shaders (GLES 2.0). You can render a mesh to fill the hole screen and darken it with some shader calculations. -- This is the most flexible option, and the most difficult (far from rocket science anyway).

Some options sound better than others, but providing the info you gave, there's nothing more I can tell you. You have a good start point from where to start to research on.

**If you choose working with textures, consider to have a couple of different textures depending on the battery. You can scale them a bit or tint them, but having different textures is way more flexible.

Comment: Alright thanks! I didn't know the stencil buffer stuff was so simple! I decided to go that route and simply draw a gradient black rectangle for a fading effect.

Answer (score 5):

If the graphic element is a `BufferedImage` or `Graphics2D` instance, you might approach it like this.

[image: Flashlight using incandescent (yellow) beam]

[image: Flashlight using halogen (blue) beam]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlashLight {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int w = 500, h = 200;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
        final BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        final BufferedImage bi2 = FlashLight.draw(
                bi, 10, 180, 420, 90, .3,
                new Color(255, 255, 120, 15), new Color(0, 0, 0, 220));
        final BufferedImage bi3 = FlashLight.draw(
                bi, 10, 180, 420, 90, .3,
                new Color(180, 250, 255, 15), new Color(0, 0, 0, 220));

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,0,2,2));
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi2)));
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi3)));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public static BufferedImage draw(
            BufferedImage source,
            double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
            double beamWidth,
            Color beamColor, Color darknessColor) {
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
              RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHints(hints);

        g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);

        // Create a conical shape to constrain the beam
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2d) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2d));
        double tangent = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        double theta = Math.atan(tangent);
        System.out.println(
                "distance: " + distance
                + "  tangent: " + tangent
                + "  theta: " + theta);
        double minTheta = theta + beamWidth / 2;
        double maxTheta = theta - beamWidth / 2;
        double xMin = x1 + distance * Math.cos(minTheta);
        double yMin = y1 + distance * Math.sin(minTheta);

        double xMax = x1 + distance * Math.cos(maxTheta);
        double yMax = y1 + distance * Math.sin(maxTheta);

        Polygon beam = new Polygon();
        beam.addPoint((int) x1, (int) y1);
        beam.addPoint((int) xMax, (int) yMax);
        beam.addPoint((int) xMin, (int) yMin);

        g.setColor(beamColor);
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                (int)x1,(int)y1, beamColor,
                (int)x2,(int)y2, darknessColor);
        g.setClip(beam);
        g.setPaint(gp);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

        // create an area the size of the image, but lacking the beam area
        Area darknessArea = new Area(new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()));
        darknessArea.subtract(new Area(beam));
        g.setColor(darknessColor);
        g.setClip(darknessArea);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

        // fill in the beam edges with black (mostly to smooth lines)
        g.setClip(null);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,xMin,yMin));
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,xMax,yMax));

        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }
}
```